# get partition size and %used from filesysteme only

Tags: linux, filesystems, docker, size

I try to get something like a `df` output ( only  used / total space in fact ) but only by `cat` some file ...

In fact i try to run a docker that can monitor host disques usage...
I can get the partition list and total size in /sys/block/ from host systemes ...
But how can i get a used ( or free ) space  ?

( i try to df the /dev/sdxN after link the /dev of my host inside the docker, but that report the udev size ... )
i try to add `priviliged: true` to the docker but i didn't see any difference ...

I know this is possible ( instana / Sematext are two full monitoring solution that can run a agent in docker ,and report host metric ... )

So do you have any idea how can i get this metric ?

Comment: A typical solution is to use a cron job to put the information in a file accessible by the monitoring agent. Would that be acceptable for you?

Comment: I use docker for doing the less action possible on the host. So i'll say no ( but if i have no choice, i keep this idea ... )